# ng-select search function not showing any result

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs, typescript

I am using angular cli version - 11.2.8 and using the ng-select version of 7.3. Currently, I am able to render the UI as expected but when I tried to search in the input box inside the select element, it didn't search anything. I look for the issue in the package detail of NPM itself then have a list of versions which are compatible with different kinds of angular CLI version. Looks like I am using the correct version, still ng-select not working as properly.

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="selectedCars">
   <ng-option *ngFor="let car of cars" [value]="car.id">{{car.name}}</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

```
 selectedCars = 3; //i also used selectedCars =[3], and selectedCars ="3", but it didn't work
  cars = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Volvo' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Saab'},
    { id: 3, name: 'Opel' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Audi' },
];
```

Comment: Typo error. In your `[(ngModel)]="selectedCar"`, but your variable was naming as `selectedCars`. Change the variable name to `selectedCar`.

Answer (score 0):

please try below code hope it will solve your problem

`<ng-select [items]="cars" bindLabel="name" bindValue="id [(ngModel)]="selectedCars"> </ng-select>`

for more detail please check the example
https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fdata-source-array-example.component.html

Comment: Hi, actually `ng-select` can works with `ng-option`, You may check [Getting started --> Usage section](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ng-select/ng-select). And your attached link was broken.

Comment: @YongShun yes my bad but the code i post is more cleaner and understandable